# Cron scheduling a HTTP request on GCP that takes ~1 hour to complete

Tags: http, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I know that for GCP cloud scheduler the max timeout is around 20 minutes for a HTTP request [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55874201/how-to-increase-cloud-scheduler-request-timeout-deadline#:%7E:text=Cloud%20Scheduler%20will%20retry%20the,15%20seconds%20and%2024%20hours.).

Is it somehow possible, on GCP (perhaps using a different service) for me to invoke an HTTP endpoint, that takes around 65 minutes to respond, every ~6 hours?

Comment: Not an answer, but in the real world, you do not want to design endpoints that take more than a few seconds/minutes to respond. Connections fail, timeout, reset, etc. Instead, redesign your endpoint to return a response with some form of identifier so that the command can continue to run asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreeing with the comments, it would be better if you restructure your application so that it doesn’t have to rely on such a long timeout period. This is due to the drawbacks that John Hanley commented on. As for your actual question, you could combine multiple services. For example, Cloud Run has a [maximum timeout](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout) of 60 minutes, which you can set up when you deploy your service.

Now, in order to run this service every 6 hours, you can make use of Cloud Workflows. Workflows is an automation tool which can be used to combine multiple GCP services in a single automated process. It can [execute Cloud Run services](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/run/tutorial-cloud-run), and you can in turn [schedule this Cloud Workflow](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/schedule-workflow) to run every 6 hours with Cloud Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

In the end what I ended up doing is creating a micro VM instance on gcp and followed this guide to manually set up a cronjob in ubuntu:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-setup-cron-jobs-in-ubuntu/