# Why is google cloud scheduler not respecting attemptDeadline

Tags: google-cloud-scheduler

I have created an http cloud scheduler task. I'm expecting it to have a maximum run time of 5 minutes. However my task is reporting **DEADLINE_EXCEEDED** after exactly 1 minute.

When I run `gcloud scheduler jobs describe MySyncTask` to view my task it reports `attemptDeadline: 300s`. The service I am calling is cloud run and I have also set a 300s limit.

I am running the task manually by clicking "force a job run" in the GUI.

After 1 minute exactly in the logs it reports DEADLINE_EXCEEDED

[image: deadline after 1 minute]

Comment: After waiting for my scheduled task to run at it's scheduled time I can confirm it does work. There seems to be a glitch in cloud scheduler where a task will not respect it's deadline setting when forced to run immediately.

Comment: Did you have a chance to check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72875530/13171940)?

Answer (score 3):

When you [execute a job](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs#console) from the GUI, it will be executed using the default `attemptDeadline` value, which is 60 seconds according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55874201/how-to-increase-cloud-scheduler-request-timeout-deadline).

If you want to run it manually, I suggest to run the job from the [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs#command-line) and pass the [`--attempt-deadline`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/create/http#--attempt-deadline) flag with the desired value, as shown on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66298820/13171940):

```bash
gcloud beta scheduler jobs update http <job> --attempt-deadline=1800s --project <project>
```